# Python multi logging - multiprocessing.pool creates duplicate log entries

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

so I am doing an analysis where we process a lot of different files using multiprocessing.Pool in order to speed up the process:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cores) as p:
      output_mp = p.map(clean_file, doc_mp_list_xlsx)
```

Where `read_file` is the function to read a file and `doc_mp_list` is a list of the complete paths.

Logging is determined using the logging module, configured such that it tracks what CPU is used:

```
import logging                      # for logging
import multiprocessing              # for getting cpu count
from utils import read_config    # for reading config

config = read_config.config

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
# CONFIGURE LOGGING FOR EACH POOL
for process in range(1, num_cores+1):
    handler = logging.FileHandler(config['logging_path'] +
                                  '\\' +
                                  str(process) + '.log')
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s*|*%(levelname)s*|*%(message)s*|*%(module)s*|*%(funcName)s*|*%(lineno)d*|*%(name)s'))

    logger = logging.getLogger("SpawnPoolWorker-" + str(process))
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(handler)


def getLogger(name):
    """
    Function to return a logger for the current process

    Arguments:
    name: ignored argument for backwards compatibility

    Returns:
    logger: logger for current process
    """
    return logging.getLogger(str(multiprocessing.current_process().name))
```

And this works correctly. However, logging creates duplicate values:

| date and time | type | message | module | function | line | worker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-05 16:42:31,199* | *INFO* | *Beginning to clean file x.pdf * | *clean_pdf* | *clean_pdf* | *22* | *SpawnPoolWorker-3 |
| 2022-12-05 16:42:30,400* | *INFO* | *Beginning to clean file x.pdf * | *clean_pdf* | *clean_pdf* | *22* | *SpawnPoolWorker-4 |

I do know understand why this happens. Also, it does not create multiple outputs. It just seems that it is a duplicate message (but with a different worker attached to it).

Does anybody have a clue why this happens? Is the configuration of mp.logging incorrect? Or is it the result of something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say `mp.logging`? Is that some particular module?

Comment: Mp logging is the logging module, configured for multiprocessing in order to also understand to what process/worker a task is assigned

Comment: Configuring needs to be done with care. Have you looked at the examples in the official documentation? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes

Comment: Can you provide the config you used ? Difficult to answer without knowing what `utils.read_config` does. And wan you show how your `clean_file` function do the logging ? Note: the parameter `name` in your `getLogger` function is not used.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from you misunderstanding how logging works in the case of multiprocessing, and in general.

Each process has its own Python, which includes its own `logging`. In the main process, you configured it. But not in the others. Their own `logging` never got configured. What you did instead was configuring the main process' `logging` many times. Each time you provided a different name to a new handler, so that when a message was received in the main process it was handled many times, writing different names. But a log message emitted in the other processes did not get handled at all.
And you sometimes use `logging.getLogger("SpawnPoolWorker-" + str(process))`, other times `logging.getLogger(str(multiprocessing.current_process().name))`, so that you may not even use the same logger' objects.

I am not surprised it does not work. Multi-process code is harder than usually expected.

What you need to do is to include the setup of the logging in each process (for example at the start of `clean_file`) instead, in a multiprocess-compatible way.

The code I used to reproduce (does not include the code for the solution) :

```py
import logging
import multiprocessing

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
for process in range(1, num_cores+1):
    handler = logging.FileHandler('log.log')  # modified the file path
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s*|*%(levelname)s*|*%(message)s*|*%(module)s*|*%(funcName)s*|*%(lineno)d*|*%(name)s'))

    logger = logging.getLogger("SpawnPoolWorker-" + str(process))
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(handler)


def getLogger():
    """
    Function to return a logger for the current process

    Arguments:
    name: ignored argument for backwards compatibility

    Returns:
    logger: logger for current process
    """
    return logging.getLogger(str(multiprocessing.current_process().name))


def clean_file(something):  # FAKE
    getLogger().debug(f"calling clean_file with {something=!r}")


doc_mp_list_xlsx = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # FAKE


with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cores) as p:
    output_mp = p.map(clean_file, doc_mp_list_xlsx)
```